# python error UnboundLocalError and issue with logic

Tags: python-3.x

This is what I've written:

```
def logic( arr , r , l ):


    arr = []
    i == 0
    
    if (arr[i]) == (i +1) * i :
        print('True')
        i = i + 1
    else :
        print('False')
    return(arr )


arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
r = int(input())
l = int(input())
print(logic(arr,r,l))
```

This is what we need:

You task is to calculate a boolean array b, where b[i] = true if there exists an integer x,
such that a[i] = (i + 1) * x and l ≤ x ≤ r. Otherwise, b[i] should be set to false.

Example

For a = [8, 5, 6, 16, 5], l = 1, and r = 3, the output should be logic(a, l, r) = [false, false, true, false, true].

```
For a[0] = 8, we need to find a value of x such that 1 * x = 8, but the only value that would work is x = 8 which doesn't satisfy the boundaries 1 ≤ x ≤ 3, so b[0] = false.
For a[1] = 5, we need to find a value of x such that 2 * x = 5, but there is no integer value that would satisfy this equation, so b[1] = false.
For a[2] = 6, we can choose x = 2 because 3 * 2 = 6 and 1 ≤ 2 ≤ 3, so b[2] = true.
```

Below is the error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment

Comment: http://net-informations.com/python/iq/equal.htm i == 0 should be i =0

Answer (score 0):

You are using i == 0. This is an equals to. This is not asigning the variable. I think you are looking for i = 0. == sign is used in If statements etc.

*Also may I ask why you are using the parameters arr , r & l in your logic function. But assign them inside the function?*
EDIT: I have not programmed in python for a while and missed the indent